# Error: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode10.1

I am getting this error

> Error : libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException (lldb)

when trying to deploy a react-native ios app to device with iOS 13.1.2. This error only happens only on iOS versions 13, in all versions less than that it is working fine, it is working fine on simulators too. Can anyone help me to debug this as i'm new to this.

Comment: I think you can try updated Xcode 11

Comment: The same happens for me on Xcode 11.2 only with real device.